# Gets rows from another table where two users have in common

Tags: mysql, database

I have a client table that stores id, firstname, lastname. The client table has rows in the 'order' table that stores id, client_id, user_id and other columns.
What I need is to return clients that belongs to user_id 5 and user_id 7 and only if both users have the same clients.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname 
  FROM client 
  WHERE id IN (SELECT client_id FROM order  WHERE user_id IN (5, 7) 
    AND sched_start > date_sub(now(), interval 6 month))
```

Per request for some data and what I am trying to achieve.
My clients table has the following

```
id  | firstname |  lastname  
1   | John      | Smith    
2   | Sarah     | Jones   
3   | Brad      | Presley
```

In my order tables I have

```
id | client_id | user_id  
1  | 2         | 5  
2  | 1         | 5  
3  | 2         | 7
```

From this result, what i would like returned is Sarah Jones since both user id 5 and 7 have that client in common.

Comment: could you add some example data and expected results? just to make things clearer

Comment: Please explain what is user and what is client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have tried this. I hope, it will help you. But if not, i think, you will get some hint.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client.Id, Firstname + ' ' + LastName as Name
FROM CLIENT
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON Client.ID = ORDERS.Client_id
where User_id in(5,7)
and Client_id iN
(SELECT Client_ID
FROM 
(SELECT Client_ID,Count(*) as o
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY Client_id
HAVING Count(*)>1) as p)
```

Few descriptions: Since u said

> if both users have the same clients.

so, it is necessary to do following *query* to check if *same* value appears *more than once* in a row.

```
SELECT Client_ID,Count(*)
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY Client_id
HAVING Count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
select c.id
  from client c
    inner join orders o
      on c.id = o.client_id and o.user_id = 5
    inner join orders o2
      on c.id = o2.client_id and o2.user_id = 7;
```

will give you a client who has an order with both user_id 5, and user_id 7.  [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d202b/1)

I'm not sure what you mean by

> and only if both users have the same clients.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this also go me in the right direction.